# how to create dialog box including images and link?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to programming.
I want to know How to show a dialog box like below screenshot. 
it includes a image and Link to another website.

[image: dialog box including images and links]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. You could get into a number of web frameworks/libraries like e.g. [Vue.js](http://vuejs.org) or [react.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/).

If you just want to do it via plain HTML + CSS i would recommend you checkout these ressources :

> I want to know How to show a dialog box like below screenshot.

For your box : [Creating a modal box](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

> it includes a image and Link to another website.

Adding Images : [Here's how to add them!](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images.asp)

About Links : [Click me!](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

I could even fashion an example for you if you give me some time.

Welcome to the community & good luck on your journey!

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your img inside an anchor  tag. see the reference https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_image

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do it (hand made, or popular ready-made solutions).

But if you gonna do it by yourself without concrete solutions, there are a few steps to make it easy:

- Create HTML code for your dialog box, including all elements;
- Create CSS for your dialog box. Dialog box will be hidden by default;
- Create JavaScript code so you can manage your dialog box behavior.

For example, we have this dialog box HTML:

```
<!-- When u click on this element dialog box appears -->
    <a id="open-dialog" href="#">Show dialog</a>
<!-- Dialog box -->
    <div id="dialog-box">
    <!-- Dialog box close button -->
    <span id="close-dialog">x</span>
    <!-- Dialog box content -->
    <p>Hello im dialog box</p>
    </div>
```

And we have CSS code for our dialog box:

```
/* Dialog box container styles */    
#dialog-box{
      display:none;/* Dialog box hidden by deafault */
      position:absolute;
      border:1px solid #333;
      padding:10px;
      width:200px; height:100px;
      top:30%; left:30%;
    }

/* Dialog box close button styles */
    #close-dialog{
      display:inline-block;
      font-weight:bold;
      float:right;
      margin-right:10px;
      font-size:18px;
      width:10px; height:10px;
      cursor:pointer;
    }
```

Next we can write JavaScript code which will show and hide our dialog box (using jQuery library from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js):

```
$(function(){

/* Bind onlick event handler for element with "open-dialog" id - our
   link element to open dialog box */
$('#open-dialog').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#dialog-box').show();
});

/* Bind onlick event handler for element with "close-dialog" id - our
   close dialog box button  */
$('#dialog-box').on('click', '#close-dialog', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#dialog-box').hide();
});

});
```

You can see working example here https://jsfiddle.net/qeenegmn/